# How to recover the specific file which got accidentally deleted in azure file share

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account, azure-files, azure-storage-files, storage-file-share

What is the exact process for recovering only the deleted file/s in Azure fileshare on the azure storage adls gen2

Answer (score -1):

ADLS Gen2 now supports soft delete feature which allows you to retain the deleted file share for atleast 7 days which you can increase as per your requirement.

When you click on the **Show deleted shares** you will be able to see the deleted shares in your storage account.

Click on the **3 dots** on the right side of the share which has been deleted and click in **Undelete** option.

[image]

You can also restore a entire file share or a specific files from a restore point created by Azure Backup. Refer [Restore Azure file shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/restore-afs) to know more.

Comment: Thanks. My scenario is, create a file share and add multiple folders and each folder may contain different files in it. Now if we delete a file from one of the created folders, then we don't have option to check show deleted file... I'm looking for retrieving that deleted file..

Comment: In this scenario you need to try with azure backup as it allows you to restore files too

Comment: @UtkarshPal, why do you mean by "Azure Backup" here? Do you mean I had to have backup done prior to file deletion or some other process like contacting Azure and begging for backup from them?